# How to hide my password when deploying nodejs through FTP

Tags: node.js, ftp, passwords

How to hide my password when deploying nodejs through FTP? 
It seems the following code will be seen by everyone in GitHub repository. 
Also, when people download my file, they can also see the password.
How to avoid this problem? Thank you very much!

```
const Client = require('ftp');
const connectionProperties = {
      host: 'ftp.example.com',
      user: '',
      password: '12345678'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to retreive all environment variables from `.env` file.

#### Installation

```
npm install dotenv
```

#### In your .env file.

```
HOST=ftp.example.com
PASSWORD=12345678
```

#### In your script file

```js
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()

const Client = require('ftp');
const connectionProperties = {
      host: process.env.HOST,
      user: '',
      password: process.env.PASSWORD
```

> Please note that you should edit `.gitignore` file ignore `.env` file from the git source control.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems I need to download git and then use the git command to delete my original .env file from cache first

Comment: Is storing passwords in .env files the standard solution? Since they are still visible and not encrypted it might be a security problem, right?

Comment: `.env` file should only be read by authorized people in your trusted team. And it should always be ignored by the version control. I personally don't encrypt those passwords since it's not exposed to anyone besides my own team. However, you can encrypt it with RSA for example.